# flow type for react prop as either of two arrays

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```
type PropTypes = {
  myProp: Array<{a: string}> | Array<{a: number}>
}
```

If I create a compoennt with PropTypes as seen above I always get the following error:

```
myProp: *Array<{a: string}>* | Array<{a: number}>,
<<< object type. This type is incompatible with
myProp: Array<{a: string}> | *Array<{a: number}>*,
```

This seems weird since using Array | Array construct generally works for simple function:

```
function foo(x: Array<First> | Array<Second>): string {
  return String(x[0]['a']);
}
No errors!
```

**EDIT:**
MichaelDeBoey's answer pointed me in the right direction and turns out that the problem occurs when we try to map the prop to anything:

```
type PropTypes = {
  myProp: Array<{a: string}> | Array<{a: number}>
}

class TestComponent extends Component<PropTypes> {
  render () {
    this.props.myProp.map(prop => prop)
    return 'whatever'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `flow` are you using?
Tried this with `v0.59.0` [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxgQDRgDeAwnDnAHalsEC+YUeLMAHI8FakIDcqVAQCe2UmAAKA7ABV5pAM5gAvA1RgwmWSrjYAXGACCePOVkAeeuStaCedGwDm3AHxgAD42dg7OrmBsAK6YAEakeP6o3IZgqJQw5Fo6atoEzKwcXGCkAB4EnAAmOgW4RQSOZuqaWgH03EA) and it just works.

Maybe you can try with the following (watch on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxgQDRgDeAwnDnAHalsEC+YUeLMAHI8FakIDcqVAQCe2UmAAKA7ABV5pAM5gAvA1RgwmWSrjYAXGACCePOVkAeeuStaCedGwDmvAD4MrmBsAK6YAEakeNwAfDSo3IZgqJQw5Fo6atoEzKwcXGCkAB4EnAAmOrm4+QSOZuqaWjEM3EA)):

```js
type PropTypes = {
  myProp: Array<{a: string} | {a: number}>,
}
```

Or maybe a bit more clear (watch on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxgQDRgDeAwnDnAHalsEC+YUeLMAHI8FakIDcqVAQCe2UmACCAZQJ50bAOZgAvA3IAuMAGd1mrdylyFygHIBXTACNSePQeNsnrvFZnyigAKAtgAKoEmHvSoYGCYsiFw2MZKeHjksgA8qubaYAA+9j5uAHw0qP5xqJQw5CZRYaRmzKwcXGCkAB4EnAAmUa247QRZSeGRpQzcQA)):

```js
type AString = {a: string};
type ANumber = {a: number};
type PropTypes = {
  myProp: Array<AString | ANumber>,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a workaround. Instead of using *map* i used the iteration with (var i = 0...):
[flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxgQDRgDeAwnDnAHalsEC+YUeLMAHI8FakIDcqVAQCe2UmAAKA7ABV5pAM5gAvA1RgwmWSrjYAXGACCePOVkAeeuStaCedGwDm3AHxgAD42dg7OrmBsAK6YAEakeP6o3IZgqJQw5Fo6atoEzKwcXGCkAB4EnAAmOgW4RQSOZuqaWgH0qaJslQlgABQAlAYAkDCkROQwMACSFZg6+gDaALqpRlD4faNE6HpgAAwSYDuOYAQAFuhaAHTYqtcmTVejPueH6ADU74P0YMDAR2x3BRKmA4FAwBNprN7uRsL0rgj+qsjEZITNSHMblEtGdeo5KugAG5+ejnS43O5XB6qBZ7JZXcjcRzAAnEpEosApDmiAhRPBsCGTdFzVIpbhAA)